# Qt Ui access without source file

Tags: qt

Can I use the `Qt design Form` without `class` as kind of `QMessageBox` in the other source file? I have a class with source file, and a ui file without source file. In Ui namespace, I can only add header files, and not ui elements. I need to add many such dialoge boxes with `QLineEdit` and `QPushButtons`.

```
namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure to understand what do you want. You just want to call an ui class created by QtDesigner in another class ? For example to create an ui inherited from QWidget then use it in a MainWindow class which contain another ui ?

Comment: Not ui class, but only ui design form without source file. say myWindow.ui, and I want to call it from mainwindow.cpp despite mainwindow.ui

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use your .ui form you need to use uic. By launching the command uic basicform.ui it will write in the output the generated. So you can do this like that:

```
uic basicform.ui > ui_basicform.h
```

then you include the ui_basicform.h in your .cpp, and to the same than when you create a normal form class (add the ui namespace, create the ui attribute, initialize it, run the setupUi method).

For example for the Form is for a QWidget, in the mainwindow.h you have

```
namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}
```

add `class Form;`
then in attribute to the MainWindow class add `Ui::Form ui_form;`

After in the mainWindow.cpp the initializer list is like :

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
```

add `ui_form(new Ui::Form)`

then in the contructor you got:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow),
    ui_form(new Ui::Form)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}
```

now it's like:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow),
    ui_form(new Ui::Form)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    QWidget* test = new QWidget(this);
    ui_form->setupUi(test);
    ui->centralWidget->layout()->addWidget(test);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. What should I pass in the setupUi method? mainWindow is of type QMainWindow, and the basicform.h is a QDialog.

Comment: in the mainWindow.h, you have a namespace named Ui in this add class Form; then after in attibute to the mainWindow add Ui::Form ui_form; then in the constructor initialize it in the initializer list ui_form(new Ui::Form) then in the constructor make a QDialog test = new QDialog(this); after ui_form->setupUi(test) then test->exec();